# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to using Hibernate with Java. I'm getting the following exception. The stuff that I found online regarding this error didn't seem to help. Any ideas?  The Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 

ApplPerfStats is not mapped [select count(c) from ApplPerfStats c]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:96)
    at com.icesoft.icefaces.samples.datatable.jpa.CustomerDAO.findTotalNumberCustomers(CustomerDAO.java:89)
    at com.icesoft.icefaces.samples.datatable.ui.SessionBean.getDataPage(SessionBean.java:189)
    at com.icesoft.icefaces.samples.datatable.ui.SessionBean.access$0(SessionBean.java:185)
    at com.icesoft.icefaces.samples.datatable.ui.SessionBean$LocalDataModel.fetchPage(SessionBean.java:245)
    at com.icesoft.icefaces.samples.datatable.ui.PagedListDataModel.getPage(PagedListDataModel.java:121)
    at com.icesoft.icefaces.samples.datatable.ui.PagedListDataModel.getRowCount(PagedListDataModel.java:100)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.datapaginator.DataPaginator.isModelResultSet(DataPaginator.java:1091)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.datapaginator.DataPaginatorRenderer.encodeBegin(DataPaginatorRenderer.java:201)
```

The place where this is called:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Long findTotalNumberCustomers() {
    EntityManagerHelper.log("finding number of Customer instances", Level.INFO, null);
    try {
        String queryString = "select count(c) from ApplPerfStats c";
        return (Long) getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString).getSingleResult();
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("find number of Appl_perf_stats failed",
                Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

The class that maps to the database table:

```
package com.icesoft.icefaces.samples.datatable.jpa;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Appl_perf_stats", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class ApplPerfStats implements java.io.Serializable {
.....
```

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding a `class` element under `persistence-unit`, in your `persistence.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence ...>

    <persistence-unit name="unit">
        <class>com.icesoft.icefaces.samples.datatable.jpa.ApplPerfStats</class>
        ...
     </persistence-unit>
<persistence>
```

I haven't done much more than that with JPA/EntityManager, so I don't know if there's a way to add an entire package. AFAIK, when using `hibernate.cfg.xml`, each persistent class has to be specified directly.

Answer (score 6):

It happened to me until I started to use the full class name, e.g.:

```
String queryString = "select count(c) from com.my.classes.package.ApplPerfStats c";
```

But I don't like this approach, because it's refactoring-unfirendly. A more tractable one would be:

```
String queryString = "select count(c) from " + ApplPerfStats.class.getName() +  c";
```

javashlook's solution seems to be a shortcut for that - but it adds more XML configuration, which I try to avoid. If only there was an annotation-based way to specify that...

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I solved by adding aspectj entries to my pom.xml see below. I guess it makes sense if you are using annotations. Otherwise you need to specify the mappings in the XML file. I had this problem from a project that was using a jar with JPA annotations.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version> <!-- NB: do use 1.3 or 1.3.x due to MASPECTJ-90 - wait for 1.4 -->
            <dependencies>
                <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
    <configuration>
        <weaveDependencies>
        <weaveDependency>                                     <groupId>your.project</groupId>                        <artifactId>your.artifact</artifactId>                     </weaveDependency>                    
        </weaveDependencies>
        </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a column to do the count on

```
select count(c.someColumn) from ApplPerfStats c
```

Or try a count(*)

```
select count(*) from ApplPerfStats c
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried both of them but still got the same exception :(

Comment: make sure you're not missing anything in your annotations.  After looking closer it looks like Hibernate doesn't think that class is mapped to a table.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue but in my case the problem was due to gradle version.
When I changed my system from linux to mac then I had to switch from **gradle-1.0-milestone-3** to **gradle-1.0-milestone-4** as milestone-3 does not work in OSX. And in gradle-1.0-milestone-4 I faced the same issue then I had to degrade my gradle version to gradle-1.0-milestone-1. Now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I was also face this problem fixed by this ...

You haven't declared your entity classes in persistence.xml config file:

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a long time on this matter, but none of the above answers solved my problem.

I had already declared the entity in the persistence.xml file.
At the end the whole problem was simply that **the name of the entity is case sensitive on my system**.

This jpql was wrong

> SELECT u FROM **user** u WHERE userId = 1?

But this one works fine

> SELECT u FROM **User** u WHERE userId = 1?