# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

i get this exception when i was running an application please  give me a solution

in my mapping file like as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="mobilserv.bo.SalesanalyzerBean" table="sales_analyzer">

        <id name="id" access="field" type="long" column="ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="name" access="field" column="name" />
        <property name="itemname" access="field" column="itemname" />
        <property name="total_qty" access="field" column="Total_qty" />     
        <property name="amount" access="field" column="Total_amount" />

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

And my entity:

```
package mobilserv.bo;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;


@Entity
@Table(name = "sales_analyzer")
public class SalesanalyzerBean {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String itemname;
    protected int total_qty;
    private double amount;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected MenuItemBean item;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected List<OrderItemBean> orderItems;
    protected List<CategoryBean> categery;

    public List<CategoryBean> getCategery() {
        return categery;
    }
    public void setCategery(List<CategoryBean> categery) {
        this.categery = categery;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getItemname() {
        return itemname;
    }
    public void setItemname(String itemname) {
        this.itemname = itemname;
    }
    public int getTotal_qty() {
        return total_qty;
    }
    public void setTotal_qty(int total_qty) {
        this.total_qty = total_qty;
    }
    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public MenuItemBean getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public void setItem(MenuItemBean item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    public List<OrderItemBean> getOrderItems() {
        return orderItems;
    }
    public void setOrderItems(List<OrderItemBean> orderItems) {
        this.orderItems = orderItems;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

Comment: please post some code ,some conf. files

Comment: can you make it clear where the exception occur in your code and show us some of your code that uses hibernate. apparently your query syntax is wrong.

Comment: Some code examples would be handy. Where do you get the exception, try adding a stacktrace, etc.

Comment: Here's a related question which shows you what might be useful to us so we can answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854978/org-hibernate-hql-ast-querysyntaxexception-with-hibernate

Comment: The exception clearly says that you have a problem with HQL query syntax. Show the query that causes the exception, please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show more and to clarify a few things, what you're currently showing is pretty confusing.

1. You're using both an `hbm.xml` mapping file and annotations. They're basically doing the same thing (providing metadata to map an entity) but they're exclusive. Use one or the other, not both together.
2. The `hbm.xml` is incomplete (it doesn't map the associations). If you're using it, it might not give the expected results.
3. It might actually be interesting to show how you create the `AnnotationConfiguration` and how your `SalesanalyzerBean` is declared in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`
4. The exception you're facing says a HQL query is syntactically incorrect. **Provide the HQL query.**